# How do I encrypt a string in a Grails domain class?

Tags: grails, encryption

For example, I created this domain class:

```
package loginproject

class User {

    String name
    String password
    Boolean state

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I think it is a good idea to encrypt the password string but I do not know where to start. What algorithm? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a complete authentication and authorization solution +1 for spring security core plugin. If you just want to encrypt a domain class or parts of it in the DB, go for http://www.grails.org/plugin/crypto.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize a plugin, such as [Spring Security core plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core). And actually, we often save *password hash* instead of its encryption.

Comment: you want to say that doing some like this: new User(name: params.name, password: params.password.toHash()).save()?

Comment: Kind of that. If you use SpringSecurity, it has the function encodePassword(). Or you can write it by your own, or use another available function/library.